# call angular components according to the URL

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building a website that no matter what url I use, the content is always the same and only one component changes. For this I am trying to do it using the app-routing and ActivatedRoute, the problem is that I don't know how to add the conditional to the components. Here is my code:

app-routing.modules.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: HomepageComponent,
    pathMatch: "full",
  },
  { path: ":property", component: HomepageComponent },
];
```

homepage.component.html

```
<app-header-slider></app-header-slider>
<app-content></app-content>

<app-test></app-test>
<app-test-one></app-test-one>
<app-test-two></app-test-two>

<app-blog></app-blog>
<app-accordion></app-accordion>
```

homepage.component.ts

```
constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
      this.name = params.get("property");
      console.log(this.name);
    });
  }
```

the `console.log(this.name)` I do to this.name comes out correct, but now I need to implement it to

```
<app-test></app-test>
<app-test-one></app-test-one>
<app-test-two></app-test-two>
```

an if statement that says for example, if the url is /test-one show me app-test-one, if it is /test-two, show me app-test-two and if the url is empty ('/') show .

but I don't know how to do the latter.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you could use `ngSwitch` to display different components based on your `name` property

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="name">
  <app-test *ngSwitchCase="'name1'"></app-test>
  <app-test-one *ngSwitchCase="'name2'"></app-test-one>
  <app-test-two *ngSwitchCase="'name3'"></app-test-two>
  <app-fallback *ngSwitchDefault></app-fallback>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: although all the answers work, the most logical for my case is this one, thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="name==='test-one'">
  <app-test-one></app-test-one>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can surround your component tags with div tag having *ngIf.

```
<div *ngIf="YOUR CONDITION">
    <app-test></app-test>
</div>
<div *ngIf="YOUR CONDITION">
    <app-test-one></app-test-one>
</div>
```